I need to update the kernel of ubuntu 22.04 ISO file
We are working on customizing the ISO of ubuntu 22.04.3 using autoinstall, here we are developing our product with specific kernel version (automirror clone version). Always the automirror clone is having higher version of kernel than the ubuntu 22.04.3 ISO (comes with 5.15.0-78 kernel), currently we are installing the higher version kernel in Late commands.
Solution we are looking is to update the kernel of ubuntu 22.04.3 ISO file, so that only one kernel will be in existence during install in both installer and target environment.
In our Build process, we are extracting the ubuntu-server-minimal.squashfs and updating the required files and using xorriso.
It will be very helpful if you provide a solution.

if you don't mind using a different application, cubic can do what you want
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:cubic-wizard/release
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends cubic

from there all you need to do is have a ubuntu iso you want to make into your own, then when you import it and change it to be a custom disk, it will take you to a terminal where you can install packages you need and remove packages that you don't need, and also let's you use your squashfs with xorriso follow upstream for more info, then when you are finished it will give you a folder with the custom iso
